# How to change the background colour for nav-bar dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im trying to expand the size of the dropdown menu but most of all im trying to change the background colour, I can only seem to change the colour of the links and the area around the links.

```css
.navbar a {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(173, 173, 173);
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(238, 176, 94);
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: rgb(48, 58, 78);
  background-color: aqua;
}

.dropdown-menu>a:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 + Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c719673ce3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  My Projects
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Python.html">Python</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="PixelArt.html">Pixel Art</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Website.html">Websites</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="raspi.html">Raspberry Pi</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Portfolio.html">My Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is the dropdown menu. I want to colour in the white, and expand the size of the dropdown menu. If this is possible, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: What you should first of all do, is provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue. Showing a couple of CSS rules, without the HTML they are supposed to apply to, tells us rather little.

Comment: @CBroe Noted :)

Comment: Instead of saying `noted` edit your question to provide the [repro] you have asked for. CSS without HTMl is useless in most cases to reproduce the issue. There is no way to really help you then doing mere guesses without you providing necessary information. Also read the description of the tags you using more carefully. `web` specifically states to not use the tag. `visual-studio` states to only use the tag when havin problem with that `IDE` not with code written in that IDE.

Comment: @tacoshy I have added the HTML

Comment: are you using bootstrap? if so, label the correct version of bootstrap you are using. The code as such can not reproduce the issue.

Comment: @tacoshy Ok I believe I have done it right, I've added the bootstrap import. Also stated bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
text-align: left;
background-color: aqua;
}
```

you used this which makes the `.dropdown-item` background in `aqua` color. If you only want the `rgba(0,0,0,1)` which is a white color in your background, you only need to remove the `background-color:aqua` from here. And to change the size of your dropdown menu, you can use `width` CSS property.

Comment: Thanks! However, whenever I change the background colour, it still isn't covering the entire dropdown, I want to fill in the white space shown in the image

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change all the background color to aqua

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
   text-align: left;
   background-color: aqua;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
   color: rgb(48, 58, 78);
   background-color : aqua;
}
```

if you want to change all the color to white

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
   color: rgb(48, 58, 78);
   background-color : #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the background color you just need to set the rule for a `.dropdown-menu` inside a `.nav-item`

```css
.nav-item .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

This selector is specific enough to override the BS style for `.dropdown-menu`.
Then expand the `.dropdown-item`s to take up the full width of the `.dropdown-menu` as follows:

```css
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  /* ... */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.navbar a {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(173, 173, 173);
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(238, 176, 94);
}

.nav-item .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: rgb(48, 58, 78);
}

.dropdown-menu>a:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 + Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c719673ce3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  My Projects
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Python.html">Python</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="PixelArt.html">Pixel Art</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Website.html">Websites</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="raspi.html">Raspberry Pi</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Portfolio.html">My Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```